# Why does nose finds tests in files with only 644 permission?

Tags: python, permissions, nose, doctest

Today I ran a bunch of doctests using Python 2.6 on a Ubuntu 9.10 with nose :

```
nosetests --with-doctest
Ran 0 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

WTF? I had tests in that files, why didn't that work?

I changed permission to 644:

```
sudo chmod 644 * -R
nosetests --with-doctest
Ran 11 test in 0.004s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

Changing it back to 777:

```
sudo chmod 777 * -R
nosetests --with-doctest
Ran 0 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

Why is that? Using 644, I can't even edit my files!

Comment: Needing-less to say, the file owner is me.

Comment: Wow, I posted that 1h ago and it's already the first entry in Google for "nose permission 644". I don't know what amaze me the most: how SO much is becoming famous, or how much Google is becoming fast.

Comment: Why can you not edit your files? 644 == -rw-r--r--

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the `--exe` flag:

```
$ nosetests --help

...    

--exe               Look for tests in python modules that are executable.
                    Normal behavior is to exclude executable modules,
                    since they may not be import-safe [NOSE_INCLUDE_EXE]
```

Comment: I would love to understand why --exe isnt the default behavior. It took a while to discover this issue! Argh!