# Why Django nose test need --exe?

Tags: django, django-nose

Why do I have to use the --exe argument while I run django-nose tests.
If I don't use it, it will skip the tests to run

e.g.

```
manage.py test myapp

Ran 0 tests in 0.000s
```

while my tests are in the correct place etc.

Running it in verbosity 3 it shows:

```
nosetests --verbosity 3 myapp
```

it shows: (changed the path names, but anyway, nose finds them but skips them!!)

```
nose.selector: INFO: /path_to_project/path_to_app/myapp/tests.pyc is executable; skipped
nose.selector: INFO: /path_to_project/path_to_app/myapp/tests.py~ is executable; skipped
```

The only way to run the tests is using the --exe argument

I Am using:

- Ubuntu (both 10.4 or 11.4 doesn't matter)
- Python 2.6 and 2.7
- Django 1.4.3

why is that?

According to the documents you won't need --exe

But after puzzling for a while... and googling and looking here, i got this suggestion.

see [Nose doesn't find Django tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12867892/nose-doesnt-find-django-tests?)

and [Nose unable to find tests in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457104/nose-unable-to-find-tests-in-ubuntu/)

But nowhere the explanation of this workaround for what seems to be a bug?

Or Am I missing something?

I requestion this, because the other questions are quite old, and no satisfactory answer to this problem found.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bug - it's a feature.

Please, see good explanations here: [What does "import safe" mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330499/what-does-import-safe-mean-in-python)